# Determine the Quarter from a date

Tags: r, date

Let say I have date as follows:

```
Date = as.Date('2020-11-30')
```

Now I want to determine the quarter for this date, So I can use the zoo package

```
library(zoo)
as.yearqtr(Date). ### [1] "2020 Q4"
```

However I want to determine the quarter with respect to a date, say

```
Date1 = as.Date("2020-05-31")
```

So with respect to this date, the quarter of Date should be `Q2`.

Is there any way to set up the base in the `quarter` calculation?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we want to extract the quarter, use `format`

```
format(as.yearqtr(Date1), 'Q%q')
[1] "Q2"
```

---

Or if it is based on difference, try

```
paste0("Q", (as.yearqtr(Date) -  as.yearqtr(Date1)) * 4)
[1] "Q2"
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not what I was looking for. I wanted to get the Quarter of `Date` w.r.t `Date1`, not the quarter of `Date1`

Comment: @BrianSmith sorry, it is not clear.  When you have two different dates, how do you assume that the 'Date' and 'Date1' are not very different

Comment: @BrianSmith did you meant a difference in days and calculate the quarter based on that

Comment: @BrianSmith please check if the updated solution logic is what you are looking for. thanks